# Using \d in regex range

Tags: regex, neovim

In neovim (v0.5.0), the regex `\d` matches any digit in the input string. The regex `[0-9]` does the same, but `[\d]` instead matches a literal `d` character, as seen in these images:

[image: \d]

[image: [0-9]]

[image: [\d]]

Is it possible to use `\d` in a character range like that, or do I have to type `[0-9]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a [POSIX bracket expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) (`[...]`), `\d` cannot be used to match digits.

However, inside a POSIX bracket expression, you can use [POSIX character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class). [Neovim supports](https://neovim.io/doc/user/pattern.html) quite a few, but in your case, you can use `[:digit:]`. So, to match either a comma or digits, you can use `[,[:digit:]]`.

In Neovim, you can **switch to [an NFA regex engine](https://neovim.io/doc/user/pattern.html#NFA)** that supports [shorthand character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) inside square brackets.

> Vim will automatically select the right engine for you.  However, if you run
> into a problem or want to specifically select one engine or the other, you can
> prepend one of the following to the pattern:
>
> `\%#=0`    Force automatic selection.  Only has an effect when
>             'regexpengine' has been set to a non-zero value.
>       `\%#=1`    Force using the old engine.
>       `\%#=2`    Force using the NFA engine.

So, you can use `[\d]` after you prepend the pattern with `\%#=2`.